# How to set new seed every time function is called

Tags: c, random, seed

I want to set new seed every time when function is called.

I have tried implementing **srand(time(NULL))** in function, that uses rand(). But that doesn't work. I also tried to implement **srand(rand())**, but every time array is generated it's elements is the same.

I have also tried adding one function (my_init()):

```
void my_init()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
}
```

```
void fillArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    srand(rand());
//    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: *I want to set new seed every time when function is called.* No, you don't.  See [`srand()` — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833)

Comment: @SteveSummit oh, I get it now. Solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: `srand(time(NULL))` will make `rand()` generate *exactly* the same value if called twice in one second. Seed once, and if you need it unpredictable for security reasons, please, *please* do not use `rand()`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question seems to be solved, but for future questions please keep in mind that "But that doesn't work." is not a useful description of what is happening. Instead better tell precisely what you expect to happen and what happens instead.